# Where is Sublime Text 2 installed

Tags: sublime-text

I was trying to make Sublime Text 2 start from the Terminal. I found a great resource but I cannot find where it is installed. I used the WebUpd8 PPA, anyone know where the PPA installs sublime.

Comment: It should be under Accessories. If it's not, try to open it via terminal with the command `sublime-text`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't know the answer to this exact question, but to know wich files did a package install you can use this command:

```
dpkg -L <package name>
```

The best thing is that you can use tab completion with it so:

```
dpkg -L subli<tab>
```

is likely to give you the answer.

You can also use Synaptic to find this list through a GUI.

Answer (score 5):

The command for starting it is most likely

```
sublime-text-2
```

though try

```
sublime-text
```

and

```
subl
```

These are the programs, or links that get installed to `/usr/bin/` (if my limited understanding of deb packages is anything to go by, I don't actually use the software).